# Airpods Pro "when last connected to this Mac" doesn't respect Android

Tags: bluetooth, android, airpods

The title pretty much says it all. I've got Airpods Pro that are paired to my work Macbook Pro and my Android phone (Oneplus 7T). I'd like them to connect to whatever device they were most recently connected to, but it seems that the option "When Last Connected to This Mac" (which I do have enabled) only respects Apple devices.

Every time I pull out my Airpods, no matter if they were connected to the Macbook or my phone most recently, they automatically connect to the Macbook, even waking it from sleep, activating work 2FA, and making it drain its battery, apart from just being plain annoying.

Is this on purpose, or a bug? My hunch is that it's an intentional bug to annoy non-Apple users into buying an iPhone, just to make the pain go away. It's even more frustrating since I am obviously an Apple customer. I have a personal Macbook, a work Macbook, and  Airpods Pros, yet they're still not satisfied and troll people who have given them many thousands of dollars just so they can extract another 900 or what have you. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why should this be a bug? Might just require some code running on the device the Airpods connect to, code which obviously doesn‘t exist in Android.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The issue you describe is frustrating, but your Mac has no way of knowing whether your AirPods were connected to another device since they were last used (the same is true for you Android phone). The problem is exacerbated by the fact that your Mac connects to your AirPods _without user intervention_, and it seems you can't prevent this from happening. Is this behavior a bug or a feature? If you use a Mac and an iPhone, it is definitely a feature: Apple tracks which device is or was connected to the AirPods using an Apple ID and (cont'd)

Comment: makes life for the user easier, because pairing is "smart" (although it doesn't work flawlessly). Unfortunately, since an Apple ID is required, it is only supported on Apple devices. On the other hand, Apple could've added an option to prevent AirPods from connecting unless the user specifically requests it. I guess it was a conscious choice not to offer that option. See https://support.apple.com/HT208718 for more information.

Comment: I know this is more of a workaround than a solution, but you may be able to mitigate this issue by using a computer sleeve that blocks EMF, like this one: https://www.safesleevecases.com/products/safesleeve-laptop-case-black. The sleeve would hopefully prevent your Mac from automatically connecting to your AirPods. If you feel this suggestion helps and solves your issue, I'd rewrite this comment into an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Your hunch is incorrect and you are wrong.

The feature you mention needs to be implemented on the computing device (computer, phone, tablet, AppleTV, whatever). As your Android phone does not support this feature - it can't work.

This is not a matter of Apple being a greedy company making the AirPods ignore everything but Apple products. It is simply the fact that this feature requires the computing device to have an implementation of the feature, and your Android phone does not.

Taken at face value, the system is actually doing exactly what you asked it for. You asked it to reconnect automatically to the AirPods if they were last connected to this Mac. In order to avoid your MacBook waking from sleep, you could simply disconnect from the AirPods every time you stop using them (i.e. select for example the internal speakers as the audio output from the menu bar).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135515/discussion-on-answer-by-jksoegaard-airpods-pro-when-last-connected-to-this-mac).